# Given $T^2=\frac12(T+T^∗)$, prove that T is normal trasformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

using the fact that:

$T = T_1 + T_2$

$T^* =  T_1^* + T_2^*$

when:

$T_1 = \frac12 (T + T^*), T_2 = \frac12 (T - T^*)$ and $T_1^* = T_1, T_2^*=-T_2$.

then:

$T^*T = (T_1^* + T_2^*)(T_1 + T_2)= T_1^*T_1 + T_1^*T_2+T_2^*T_1+T_2^*T_2 = T_1^2 + T_1T_2-T_2T_1 + T_2^2$

$TT^* = (T_1 + T_2)(T_1^* + T_2^*)= T_1T_1^* + T_1T_2^*+T_2T_1^*+T_2T_2^* = T_1^2 - T_1T_2+ T_2T_1 + T_2^2$.

how can i use the fact that $T^2=\frac12(T+T^∗)$ to show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ commute?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578083/given-t-is-normal-trasformation-and-t2-frac12-tt-prove-that-t2-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The relation

$$T^2 = \frac12(T+T^\ast)$$

allows you to express $T^\ast$ as a polynomial in $T$: $T^\ast = P(T)$.

Comment: got it! it was in front of my eyes :D thanx

Comment: I can never understand why one would accept an answer and not upvote it simultaneously. +1.

Comment: sorry for that... :) +1

Comment: @ julien:  it happens when someone doesn't yet have enough rep. to upvote!